# Highchart value with their units

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I am drawing a column chart using highcharts.dll. I want to show chart value and their units also. (Ex. "Deisel 521452.30 liters" or "Electricity 5124.60 units")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use a formatter.

```
Formatter = "function() { return 'Electricity <b>'+ this.point.value +'</b> units'; }"
```

Example :-

```
Highcharts chart = new Highcharts("ColumnChart")
            .InitChart(new Chart { DefaultSeriesType = ChartTypes.Column })
            .SetTitle(new Title { Text = "Monthly Average Rainfall" })
            .SetSubtitle(new Subtitle { Text = "Source: WorldClimate.com" })
            .SetXAxis(new XAxis { Categories = new[] { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" } })
            .SetYAxis(new YAxis
                      {
                          Min = 0,
                          Title = new YAxisTitle { Text = "Rainfall (mm)" }
                      })
            .SetLegend(new Legend
                       {
                           Layout = Layouts.Vertical,
                           Align = HorizontalAligns.Left,
                           VerticalAlign = VerticalAligns.Top,
                           X = 100,
                           Y = 70,
                           Floating = true,
                           BackgroundColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFFFF"),
                           Shadow = true
                       })
            .SetTooltip(new Tooltip { Formatter = @"function() { return ''+ this.x +': '+ this.y +' mm'; }" })
            .SetPlotOptions(new PlotOptions
                            {
                                Column = new PlotOptionsColumn
                                         {
                                             PointPadding = 0.2,
                                             BorderWidth = 0
                                         }
                            })
            .SetSeries(new[]
                       {
                           new Series { Name = "Tokyo", Data = new Data(new object[] { 49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4 }) },
                           new Series { Name = "London", Data = new Data(new object[] { 48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2 }) },
                           new Series { Name = "New York", Data = new Data(new object[] { 83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0, 84.5, 105.0, 104.3, 91.2, 83.5, 106.6, 92.3 }) },
                           new Series { Name = "Berlin", Data = new Data(new object[] { 42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6, 75.5, 57.4, 60.4, 47.6, 39.1, 46.8, 51.1 }) }
                       });

        return View(chart);
```